# Spacing out two separate strings in C#

Tags: c#, string

```
using System;

namespace Starter
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main() {   
            //Variable declarations and initialization (assignment)//
            int venusMoonCount = 0;
            float windSpeed = 450.0f;
            string venusFact = "Venus is the only planet" + " that rotates clockwise.";
            //Display the variable values.//
            Console.WriteLine(venusFact);
            Console.Write("Total moons = ");
            Console.WriteLine(venusMoonCount);

            Console.Write("Venusian windspped = ");
            Console.WriteLine(windSpeed + " miles/hr");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to run this exercise, when it comes to

string venusFact = "Venus is the only planet" + " that rotates clockwise.";

It won't add the space between the two strings. It outputs

"Venus is the only *planetthat* rotates clockwise
Total moons = 0
Venusian windspped = 450 miles/hr"

How do separate "planetthat"?

[image: Here's a picture of the output]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It has the space for me. Can you upload a screenshot to show this? Your solution could be corrupt, try a Clean Build. If that doesn't work, close the solution and delete the Bin and Obj folders and the .suo file then reopen the solution and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. Are you compiling it?
The display result should be:

```
Venus is the only planet that rotates clockwise.
Total moons = 0
Venusian windspped = 450 miles/hr
```

Note that you could use the + to just make 3 Console.WriteLine

EDIT: on your screenshot you don't have the dot "." either so clearly this is not the output of your code. Check if you execute what you want to compile.

Comment: It could be because i'm running it through the terminal.

Comment: Ok now I can see it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, it happens all the time not to be running the code we thought we were compiling!